# Há erro de concordância de gênero quando há dois substantivos de gêneros opostos?

Tags: concordância, gênero

Os termos **Lojas Online** e **Marketplace** na frase abaixo são de gênero feminino e masculino, respectivamente, e sucedem os adjetivos "das maiores" e "mais antigas", que são femininos. A frase está correta ou tem erro de concordância?

"A Americanas é uma das maiores e mais antigas **lojas online** e **marketplace** do Brasil."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Quando há mais do que um substantivo, o adjetivo deve concordar com
> aquele que está mais próximo. Exemplo:
>
> Que bonita pintura e poema! Que bonito poema e pintura!

[concordância nominal](https://www.todamateria.com.br/concordancia-nominal/)

marketplace não é português. Além disso, *o uso em inglês não funciona aqui*, se por exemplo você fosse traduzir a frase. Muitas vezes, jovens redatores faltam um pouco de cultura. Como o adjetivo antecede, acho que o feminino está correto.

Só que:  Lojas Americanas seria [plural](https://canaltech.com.br/empresa/lojas-americanas/)

marketplace = lugar de compra ou varejista

Eu usaria:

*As Lojas Americanas são uma das maiores e mais antigas lojas online e varejistas do Brasil.*